# Yii CSRF disable for action

Tags: php, yii, csrf

I send same form data from different contollers and subdomain. But in one case I need disable CSRF validation.

Example:

Login form:

- Location 1: main page example.com
- Location 2: account.example.com/login
- Location 3: `gate.example.com`

And I need disable validation just in case when I send data from location 1 to location 2.

I Used `$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',...`

How can I do that?

I supose that csrf cookie is not crossdomain!

Comment: Thanks guys. There is no way. I have to decline from this idea. That not exact what I mean. In my case I have to check refferer

Comment: You could check referer in `normalizeRequest` too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a name suggest it is *Cross-Site-Request-Forgery*, so no it is not crossdomain and **must** not be:)

CSRF is enabled in request component, so just get request component and reconfigure it:

```
Yii::app()->request->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Im not quite sure where to put it, probably in the beginning of action.

Comment: Thx. I suspected) I tried to locate this line everywhere, but nothing happened

Comment: Try in `init` method of your controller, i was setting `$_POST` value of csrf and it worked fine.

Comment: I've noticed that i have customized http request component. csrf validation is attached to `onBeginRequest` event of application component in method `normalizeRequest` in `CHttpRequest`. You could subclass `CHttpRequest` and tweak with it.

Answer (score 31):

CSRF validation occurs early in the process of loading the webpage, even before a controller is called. You want to override the CHttpRequest class to tell it to ignore certain routes.

Create a file in your `protected/components` folder named `HttpRequest.php` and add the following contents.

```
class HttpRequest extends CHttpRequest
{
    public $noCsrfValidationRoutes=array();

    protected function normalizeRequest()
    {
            //attach event handlers for CSRFin the parent
        parent::normalizeRequest();
            //remove the event handler CSRF if this is a route we want skipped
        if($this->enableCsrfValidation)
        {
            $url=Yii::app()->getUrlManager()->parseUrl($this);
            foreach($this->noCsrfValidationRoutes as $route)
            {
                if(strpos($url,$route)===0)
                    Yii::app()->detachEventHandler('onBeginRequest',array($this,'validateCsrfToken'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, edit your config file in `protected/config` with the following information:

```
    // application components
'components'=>array(
    ....

    'request' => array(
        'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
        'class'=>'HttpRequest',
        'noCsrfValidationRoutes'=>array(
            'controllername/actionname',
        ),
    ),
 )
```

Comment: Example of `controllername/actionname` is: `'api2/getAssociated'`

Answer (score 8):

To disable CSRF add this code to your controller:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: Yii 2 system, at date of topic : no Yii 2

Answer (score 3):

Disable your CSRF from the controller:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{

    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

See: https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/csrf/#disabling-csrf-protection

Answer (score 2):

To disable csrf add this in your main.php

```
return array(
'components'=>array(
    'request'=>array(
        'enableCsrfValidation'=>false,
    ),
),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable CSRF add this code to your controller:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    Yii::app()->request->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to disable it for certain actions

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    Yii::$app->request->enableCsrfValidation = $action->id !== 'index'; //action name to disable CSRF for
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this slightly differently from willem-renzema 's approach.

```
<?php
class HttpRequest extends CHttpRequest
{
    public $noCsrfValidationRoutes=array();

    public function validateCsrfToken($event) { 
        $url=Yii::app()->getUrlManager()->parseUrl($this);
        foreach($this->noCsrfValidationRoutes as $route)
        {
            if(strpos($url,$route)===0)
                return true;
        }
        return parent::validateCsrfToken($event);
    }
}
```

Configuring it is the same as with his answer, but his method gave me errors, because it was not always possible to get the url with `$url=Yii::app()->getUrlManager()->parseUrl($this);` in the `normalizeRequest()` function.